# How to detect geo blocking in a browser

Tags: javascript, amazon-cloudfront

How to detect whether or not a user or resource is being geo-blocked?

###### Given

- Two *AWS CloudFront Distributions*:

  - Website at `www.example.com`
  - 2nd domain at `videos.example.com` which is geo-restricted/blocked via [CloudFront geo restriction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/georestrictions.html)
- CORS is working, it is possible to execute requests from the website towards the video CDN if user is **not geo blocked**
- When a user accesses the video CDN he'll see `http/403 Forbidden` or `http/200 OK` depending on this geo location.

###### Problem

A geo blocked user cannot probe resources from the restricted CDN and check the return code being either `http/200 OK` or `http/403 Forbidden`:

Since the requests originates from `www.` and then send towards a different domain `video.` it is a **different domain** so the browser must send a **CORS/preflight** requests. But this request will be blocked due to the geo restriction.

From JavaScript perspective it simply fails the *CORS preflight* with no error details.

I tried fetching different ContentTypes in combination with `fetch mode: cors/no-cors` that would qualify for a [Simple Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests) and thus not require CORS — but no success so far.

Comment: If you can't get the server to tell you its geo-blocking, the only other way is to try connections from other geos. Even that may not be enough if you are unable to determine a geo that is not blocked. There can also be other reasons unrelated to geo-blocking, such as being blacklisted, which my not be differentiable from geo-blocking.